# Android custom dropdown/popup menu

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu, android-menu, popupmenu

How do I do a custom dropdown/popup menu anchored to a button?

I need it to work like the popup menu (anchored to a view), and do something when I click an item from the menu.

How do I add items to the menu by code, keeping menu's height and make it scrollable if there are more than 5 items. I don't need to add any images, just text.

[image]

Answer (score 354, accepted):

**Update**: To create a popup menu in android with Kotlin refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48628108/2462531).

To create a popup menu in android with Java:

Create a layout file `activity_main.xml` under `res/layout` directory which contains only one button.

Filename: `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"  
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"  
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >  

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/button1"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"  
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"  
        android:text="Show Popup" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Create a file `popup_menu.xml` under `res/menu` directory

It contains three items as shown below.

Filename: `poupup_menu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/one"  
        android:title="One"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/two"  
        android:title="Two"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/three"  
        android:title="Three"/>  

</menu>
```

MainActivity class which displays the popup menu on button click.

Filename: `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
    private Button button1;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button1);
                //Inflating the Popup using xml file
                popup.getMenuInflater()
                    .inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

                //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                popup.show(); //showing popup menu
            }
        }); //closing the setOnClickListener method
    }
}
```

To add programmatically:

```
PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(this, view);

menu.getMenu().add("One");
menu.getMenu().add("Two");
menu.getMenu().add("Three");

menu.show();
```

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784088/setting-popupmenu-menu-items-programmatically) link for creating menu programmatically.

Comment: Hey thank you!! What if I want to add more items to the menu?. Can I do that by code?

Comment: welcome.. yes you can add more items in popup_menu.xml

Comment: But how can I do it in my main class? How can I add items via java?

Comment: Ok I found out how to add items: menu.getMenu().add("item"); But how can I customize the menu?

Comment: you can customize it like by using `popup.getMenu().add(groupId, itemId, order, title);`

Comment: I mean the width, the background, etc.

Comment: Once refer this it may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591164/how-to-change-menu-item-color-size-programmatically

Comment: @DavidStanete If this provides a solution to your question, don't forget to mark this answer as accepted. If you have any follow-up questions, feel free to ask a new question and provide a link.

Comment: Now it can also be used in lower versions ie  below 3.0(honeycomb) by using the v7 compat support library..

Comment: @Mr.G Yes, You can add icon too by adding this line in popup_menu.xml
`android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"` in every menu item

Comment: <item
        android:id="@+id/google_plus"
        android:title="@string/menu_google_plus"
        android:icon="@drawable/add_by_gp"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    /> this is how i added , but i cant see  image with text

Comment: Replace this `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` with `app:showAsAction="always|withText"`

Comment: i replaced with app:showAsAction="always|withText" , but it gives me an error, i put android:showAsAction="always|withText", but it didnt give me an image

Comment: is there an image `add_by_gp` in drawable folder??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58853/discussion-between-mr-g-and-shylendra).

Comment: @ShylendraMadda Heyy thanks, this is really needfull.

Comment: Glad to helped you.. @anuragshrivastava

Comment: @FloWe for that you might look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782846/popup-menu-in-custom-listview

Comment: @ShylendraMadda thanks, but i meant setting a custom adapter for the Popup to display items instead of XML Menues.

Comment: @FloWe It should be a new question

Answer (score 14):

I know this is an old question, but I've found another answer that worked better for me and it doesn't seem to appear in any of the answers.

Create a layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingStart="10dip"
    android:paddingEnd="10dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/shoe_select_icon"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shoe_select_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Create a ListPopupWindow and a map with the content:

```
ListPopupWindow popupWindow;
List<HashMap<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(TITLE, getString(R.string.left));
    map.put(ICON, R.drawable.left);
    data.add(map);
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(TITLE, getString(R.string.right));
    map.put(ICON, R.drawable.right);
    data.add(map);
```

Then on click, display the menu using this function:

```
private void showListMenu(final View anchor) {
    popupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(this);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            this,
            data,
            R.layout.shoe_select,
            new String[] {TITLE, ICON}, // These are just the keys that the data uses (constant strings)
            new int[] {R.id.shoe_select_text, R.id.shoe_select_icon}); // The view ids to map the data to

    popupWindow.setAnchorView(anchor);
    popupWindow.setAdapter(adapter);
    popupWindow.setWidth(400);
    popupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    devicesAdapter.setSelectedLeftPosition(devicesList.getChildAdapterPosition(anchor));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    devicesAdapter.setSelectedRightPosition(devicesList.getChildAdapterPosition(anchor));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    devicesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    popupWindow.show();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The Kotlin Way

```
fun showPopupMenu(view: View) {
    PopupMenu(view.context, view).apply {
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_men, menu)
                setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                    Toast.makeText(view.context, "You Clicked : " + item.title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    true
                }
            }.show()
}
```

**UPDATE:** In the above code, the apply function returns `this` which is not required, so we can use `run` which don't return anything and to make it even simpler we can also remove the curly braces of showPopupMenu method.

Even Simpler:

```
fun showPopupMenu(view: View) = PopupMenu(view.context, view).run {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_men, menu)
            setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                Toast.makeText(view.context, "You Clicked : ${item.title}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                true
            }
            show()
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

First, create a folder named “menu” in the “res” folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="Add"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        android:title="Edit">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Then, create your Activity Class:

```
public class PopupMenu1 extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popup_menu_1);
    }

    public void onPopupButtonClick(View button) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, button);
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popup.getMenu());

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(PopupMenu1.this,
                        "Clicked popup menu item " + item.getTitle(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        popup.show();
    }
}
```