# Android: How can show overflow menu exactly on the upper Action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

I have an overflow menu in my action bar , it shown in some devices on the upper action bar and in other devices shown in the below action bar, I want to show my overflow menu on the upper action bar in all devices. Please help me.

my overflow menu :

```
<item
android:id="@+id/menu_overflow"
android:icon="@drawable/color"
android:orderInCategory="11111"
android:showAsAction="always">
<menu>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/whitecolor"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/colorwhite"
        android:title="white"/>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/yellowcolor"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/coloryellow"
        android:title="yellow"/>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/redcolor"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/colorred"
        android:title="red"/>


    <item
        android:id="@+id/bluecolor"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@drawable/colorblue"
        android:title="blue"/>
</menu>
</item>
```

and my code :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
    {       
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {         
            case R.id.whitecolor:           

                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.yellowcolor:

                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.redcolor:

                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.bluecolor:

                finish();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: you have to use custom action bar menu to achieve this.

Comment: Please use android:showAsAction="always". If you want your icon to show always on top of actionbar. If you have any query please let me know.

Comment: @Vivek Thanks, as you see, my overflow menu have android:showAsAction="always" , but still it shown in below action bar

Comment: if i see you menu. your 4 menu items has  android:showAsAction="never".

Comment: @Vivek Ok, i had changed and still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. For example. if you want more then create layout and set it to your action bar.

```
      ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions()
                | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        ImageView imageView_done = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
        imageView_done.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView_done.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_done);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
                | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
        );
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 40;
        imageView_done.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        actionBar.setCustomView(imageView_done);
```

Comment: Thanks,how can i use this?

Comment: paste your activity or fragment code that where you want to implement. You have to add this code in your activity oncreat().

Comment: Thanks, its shown exactly in the upper actionbar, now how can make it to be an overflow menu?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329132/android-custom-dropdown-popup-menu refer this link and merge with your current code. definitely you can get answer.

Comment: thats work, but my items have icon, that does not shown in popup menu.

Comment: please don't forget to mark it as an answer if it works. show your menu layout then I'll help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you've developed your application for **Android 2.3.x (API level 10)** or lower, the contents of your options menu appear at the bottom of the screen when the user presses the Menu button, as shown in below figure.

[image]

If you've developed your application for **Android 3.0 (API level 11)** and **higher**, items from the options menu are available in the action bar. By default, the system places all items in the action overflow, which the user can reveal with the action overflow icon on the right side of the action bar (or by pressing the device Menu button, if available). To enable quick access to important actions, you can promote a few items to appear in the action bar by adding `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to the corresponding `<item>` elements

[image]

OR

Try to used [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html), you can show the overflow on all versions and all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use Material Design it has built in support due to its design philosophy