# How to change the view of Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

How to change the Spinner view like in the picture? After i pick rows i dont want the Spinner show me the result on it, Just keep the "some Image" without get the result on the Spinner View
[image]

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want the result of the spinner to be an image?

Comment: I want the spinner act like a "ImageButton" . and not return the text result on him.

Comment: @Anna http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329132/android-custom-dropdown-popup-menu

Comment: @Anna Please check my above comment & below answer .I hope it helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popup menu is an overflow menu like Spinner actions. PopupMenu is available from API level 11.Android Popup Menu displays the menu below the anchor text if space is available otherwise above the anchor text. It disappears if you click outside the popup menu.

For this,Please check this demo [android-popup-menu-example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example) And [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329132/android-custom-dropdown-popup-menu) .

You can read more about PopupMenu here

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use **`Button`** with **`ContextMenu`** or **`PopupMenu`** set for that button.
http://javatechig.com/android/android-popup-menu-example

Comment: It's very good! but there is no way to change the spinner view?