# What is this menu called?

Tags: android, android-menu

I'm trying to implement a similar menu into my android app. I cannot figure out what this menu is called.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot7GA.gif

Comment: It is a popup with custom view.

Comment: that's an action bar button. Read here for more information https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Answer (score 0):

It is called a popup menu with a dropdown list.
Refer to this post for more info: [Android custom dropdown/popup menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329132/android-custom-dropdown-popup-menu)