# Cracking Android Google Map details view

Tags: android, google-maps

[Google Map Location screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j1bv.png)

Hi all,

I lost my old stackoverflow account, had to start from scratch now. Any how...

I am trying to understand the implementation for Google Maps Android app. I want to create a similar screen where, the recycler view will scroll up to the toolbar. I have implemented the same with NestedScrollView and BottomSheet Behavior. 
But my question is about the list items. Especially the timings sections shows an **expandable option**, are these

- Cardview with visibility toggle added via adapter or
- Are they RecyclerView.ItemDecoration

Please help in understanding the best way to achieve this.

Happy coding..

Comment: Could you show us what you have been trying to do so far?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a recyclerview layout. It looks like a coordinator layout with a nested collapsingtoolbarlayout and a nestedscrollview. [Here](https://www.journaldev.com/13927/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example) is a link to an example on how to set one up. Also, here is a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTYuLho5_rE) on how to set one up if you'd rather learn that way.

<--Edit-->

Also, the "Save in your lists" is a popup menu like the default settings button. An implementation of this is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329132/android-custom-dropdown-popup-menu) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for your response. But my question is not about the collapsible view, its about the items in it. Especially the 'Expandable view' for store timings(Ref. Screen shot).