# How to hide action Overflow menu (Not menu item) from activity and keep in Fragment? [Not solved]

Tags: android

I have a requirement that action Overflow menu icon should show in fragment, but not activity.

Code:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.filter:
                openFilterDialog();
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }


@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mail_list, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.dwisehealthcare.pmstablet.consult.activity.ConsultActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        android:title="Filter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_filter_list_24"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

I searched, but everyone is talking about menu item, not action icon.

Comment: what do you mean by action icon ?

Comment: @MdAman Overflow icon which is in toolbar we can set through menu item

Comment: what is your requirement first you should clear that with image

Comment: @MdAman The overflow menu should show in fragment, but not activity

Comment: you can try popUpMenu

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21329225/12837534) link may be it will help you, with the help of this you can add menu anywhere you want.Just add an ImageView to that fragment and when you click that imageView you create a PopUpMenu