# Android make menu in activity and not in the action bar

Tags: android, menu

I want to make a menu in the middle of my screen, but I can't find a way to do this. How can I make a 3 dots (more vert) button without the background? only the 3 dots?

Comment: you need popup Menu: >  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329132/android-custom-dropdown-popup-menu

Comment: Thank you. But how can I create a 3 dots button without a background?

Comment: just take a imageview and set 3 dot icon on that image amd set click listner as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using Popup Menu

activity_main.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="showPopUp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

menu_popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_1"
        android:title="Item1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_2"
        android:title="Item2"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_3"
        android:title="Item3"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_4"
        android:title="Item4"/>

</menu>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
fun showPopUp(view: View) {
    val menu = PopupMenu(this,view)
    menu.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup)
    menu.show()
}
```

[image]